# Reviving the Jewish-Date series

Tags: discussion, scope

The tag [jewish-date-series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jewish-date-series) has some serious scope issues, as it is about history of Jews as much as about Judaism.

I am considering reviving it in the form of "This date is significant in Judaism because ..."

Of course, that would invalidate some answers or parts of answers in the current series, but it seems like a fun project.

Is this worth doing?

Comment: While I can't speak for others, I don't particularly find Jewish dates to be fun or interesting. I think that an [Answerathon](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/3015/26164) might be much more widely enjoyed. (*and also has no scope issues*)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure whether it's worth doing. (No litotes intended.) But don't let invalidation of old answers deter you: if they were out of scope, they should ideally be deleted (and the questions modified to be on-topic) anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The [mi-yodeya-series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) questions have sort of been "grandfathered in" ("patriarched in"?) as an exception to our general scope-rules.

I don't see a need to extend the same benefits to this series which never really caught on and isn't particularly thematically connected to the site's name. I move to close them all (perhaps with historical locks) unless you do make some changes soon.

Comment: No time to figure out how to search chat, but the idea of [tag:mi-yodea-series] being out of scope came up in chat not that long ago and the consensus was it was still in scope.

Comment: Well, I double checked, and you were [right](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17801504#17801504)

Comment: Does the downvoter think this series should be grandfathered in? Can they please comment to explain why?

Comment: FTR, I think that the most recent formulation of mi-yodeya-series questions renders them fully in-scope, regardless of their heredity. Older formulations, maybe not. I agree that the existing formulation of jewish-date-series is off-topic, and that all of its questions should be altered or closed.

Comment: I downvoted just to say not to go closing them all "soon". I thought that if I left it upvotes could just make it happen too quickly.

Comment: @Yishai What would be the problem with that? They can always be reopened.

Comment: I second (third?) the call to close them all.  If we rework them then answers may need to be reworked, so leaving them open for more now, beyond the ones that are already there, makes that job harder.  These questions as written are off-topic and we should signal that through the (reversible) act of closing them.

Answer (score 2):

I modified a question as a [sample](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4518/history-of-2-teveis). If the change to the series never goes anywhere, then lets just roll that back.

Up vote this if you think the effort is of any significance or interest.