# Should questions be immune from consideration for closing after a certain time, number of upvotes or number of answers?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

This question [Experience-based advice for focusing and slowing down prayers?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/190/experience-based-advice-for-focusing-and-slowing-down-prayers) came up for review as being too broad.

The question has 28 upvotes and 24 answers and was first posted in 2010.

Is it reasonable to reconsider the appropriateness of a question that is

so old

so much upvoted and

so much answered?

Comment: Related: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/conversation/the-mi-yodeya-series-often-mispronounced-ranges-from-permissible-to-a-torah-vio, https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3382, and the comments on the latter.

Comment: My upvote on this question means "I think this is an appropriate question to discuss on meta", not an expression of an opinion either way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in my opinion. The very fact that the software allows for it means that it's expected that the community may decide, even much later, that a question is off-topic or otherwise should be closed to further answers. (This is in contrast to some other things, like migration to another site, which are impossible after a certain amount of time.) Note also that site policy and mores can change over time and IMO it's good to be able to close old questions to reflect those changes.

(The particular question you mentioned is not closureworthy, IMO, but that's not what you asked.)

Comment: Note as well the existence of the historical lock for exactly the case of changed standards

Comment: Yes, it should be immune?

Comment: @DonielF, I was answering "Is it reasonable…?".

Comment: A historical lock also locks voting.  I've seen old, popular, previously-on-topic questions closed on other sites without the lock, and I think that's ok -- we can still reward somebody for a well-asked question back in 2010 (or a good answer) even if the question is no longer a good fit.  I'd prefer to reserve historical locks for questions where there is some larger problem.