# PTIJ: Worst post contest: 5778

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

Have you seen (or written) a post on Mi Yodeya that you thought was really silly for missing a really obvious problem? Let's have a contest to help you tell everyone about it!

This contest has one phase: Nomination and Voting. It is currently in the **Nomination and Voting** phase.

1. **Nomination and Voting** - ending March 1, 2018

   Post an answer to this Meta post containing a link to the Mi Yodeya post you want to nominate. Posts that are **already posted** are eligible (no, not including [Purim Torah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated) answers).

   Please link to one post in each entry. Nominate as many posts as you like in separate answers to this post.

   *When you see a big problem, don't wait; post a link to it here before you forget!*

   Please *do* vote on any answers to this post during the Nomination and Voting phase.

[image: 300-point Bounty button][2]]

The author of the highest voted answer to this meta post will receive a bounty of 300 points after completion of the event on March 1, 2018. In case of a tie, I will just keep the points to myself.

---

<sup>Concept and words stolen from [Meta.MY](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-contest).</sup>

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

---

## Moreover, answers must critique in the spirit of [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah). Critiques which are not offered in jest will be deleted as nonanswers!

Comment: Really funny ... Are you serious about offering the bounty or is that a joke, too?

Comment: @danf im serious. I'm also serious about the rule for ties.

Comment: It takes real self-control to not post "critiques which are not offered in jest"...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I nominate the question: [Implications of Samoa skipping a Friday](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12760/170)

Currently our [lowest-scoring](//stackoverflow.com/q/17218964) question, it has two major flaws:

1. It refers to "the island of Samoa", when in fact Samoa comprises several islands. Although Isaiah (40:15) says "הֵן אִיִּים כַּדַּק יִטּוֹל / he'll take them islands as scant", it's clear from the context that the "he" is Mr. Mid'li and not our OP.
2. The entire question is premised on the idea that "one cannot 'jump' into the middle of Shabbat". But the only support offered for that claim is a Mi Yodeya post about Australia. Besides the general unreliability of Mi Yodeya, there's the issue of the relevance of Australia to a question about Samoa. The two countries could scarcely be more different; as just one example, Australia gazes (Psalms 119:6, "Oz won't be shamed when it gazes") whereas Samoa listens (Deuteronomy 11:13, "it shall be that Samoa will listen").

Answer (score 10):

[mevaqesh's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80705/2) to [Source that hearing the Megillah does not require Hebrew understanding?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80703/source-that-hearing-the-megillah-does-not-require-hebrew-understanding) is fundamentally defective in multiple ways:

- It tries to answer the question by starting with an assumption that the question is wrong. The question asks for a source that understanding the Megillah in Hebrew is not required, and the very first the answer cites is - you guessed it - Megillah in Hebrew!

  > The Mishna in Megillah (2:1) states:
  >
  > > והלועז ששמע אשורית יצא

  Apparently, understanding the Megillah in Hebrew is necessary to even read this answer!
- All of the sources cited are about "foreigners," while the question is about people who don't understand Hebrew. It happens to be that most Americans do not understand Hebrew, while most people who do - Israelis, in particular - are foreigners. Citing these sources completely misses the point of the question.
- The second source cites [a music festival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravinia_Festival) for some reason, saying:

  > Do [even] we know the meaning "ahashtranim b'nei haramakhim'(Ester 8:10)?

  I guess this Ravinia never heard of [Sefaria.org](http://sefaria.org) or saw our [frequent ads](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4487/2) for them, because if you [look there](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.8.10?lang=bi), you can see that this phrase means "riding steeds, bred of the royal stud." Ravinia's ignorance is hardly good proof that the rest of us should water down our observance.

Answer (score 4):

I nominate the question: [Shelosha Vetishim Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2890/shelosha-vetishim-mi-yodeya)

I mean, come on. Ninety three? Seriously? Ninety two or ninety four I hear, but let's just be serious here, people. Have some self respect.

Comment: 93 is pretty significant though. I mean, it _is_ the number of gold and silver utensils that were used for the daily service in the Beis Hamikdash. (Tamid 3:4)

Answer (score 3):

I nominate [Tish'a Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/549/16354) for worst post.

Why, even children know that such a question is based on something that does not exist, based on the known saying:

> Why was six afraid of seven?  Because seven ate nine!
>
> (למה שש פחדה משבע? כי שבע אכלה תשע! (תרגום שלי

Therefore, 9 doesn't exist, and there certainly cannot be a question about it.

(The only Limud Zechus I could have for it is that maybe it is asking for memories of 9 before it was eaten by 7, but this is not stated in the question.)

Comment: I always heard the punchline as ״כי שבע שמנה תשע״ but honestly I never understood the joke. I mean, who cares that 7 got fat?

Comment: @DoubleAA 7 got fat because it ate nine, and nine was in its stomach.

Answer (score -1):

I would normally nominate the entire [mi-yodeya-series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) tag for the reasons listed below, but since I have to pick one post and I’m not making 349<sup>1</sup> entries here, I’m going to nominate the first one: [Echad - mi yodeya?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/378/9682).

You see, riddle questions are expressly forbidden on this site, yet we insist on [not slaying this tag with a jawbone](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/141/).

I’ve heard some mumbo jumbo about being [patriarched in](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3382/), to the exclusion of popular series like the [jewish-date-series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jewish-date-series).

And it’s all because of this one question: who knows one.

You know what I think? It’s just because Isaac Moses started it. Since he’s the same one who, you know, started the place, we wouldn’t be able to challenge [mi-yodeya-series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) because that would be tantamount to denying Mi Yodeya.

For those reasons, I vote for [Echad - mi yodeya?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/378/9682), because if not for that one, two never would have happened.

Though I guess we’re nowhere near [1102](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6430/9682) yet.

Further, even Isaac admits to the stupidity of this series: the accepted answer was [Brand spanking cool new jewish Q & A site.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/379/9682) Seriously? [One G-d](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16377/9682) didn’t win?!<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>347 tagged [mi-yodeya-series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) and 2 tagged [purim-torah-in-jest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest).

<sup>2</sup>No hard feelings, Isaac. I had to critique in jest to keep this up.

Answer (score -1):

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37600/5275) to my question [Can a deaf person be a shaliach tzibbur?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37587/5275) is so poor that I can understand why it's the only answer there. I think it scared off everyone else from answering the question.

The first paragraph says the Taz wasn't fond of having a deaf Shaliach Tzibbur.

Ummm, hello?? When I said "deaf" did it occur to anyone that I didn't mean ear deaf, I meant tone deaf? I mean, I grew up listening to a really great professional chazzan, the likes of Moshe Oisher, Yossele Rosenblatt and Ben Tzion Shenker. I know what a good chazzan sounds like.

Have you heard some of these *Ba'alei Tefilla* these days? They sing off key and they try to show off their fake falsetto skills by singing some old *niggun* from Carlebach from 1963 and expect everyone to sing along during *Kedusha* for 15 minutes. And they think they're good! And this guy cites the 3 rabbis that says not to remove him??? And the Taz just says, "Oh, I'm not fond of the idea". The Taz shouldn't even consider the thought in the first place. This guy shouldn't even be allowed to sing at all in public!

Thank goodness at least he cited an opinion from Rav Akivah Eiger, but that should have been the only opinion cited.