# PTIJ: Worst post contest: 5779

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

Have you seen (or written) a post on Mi Yodeya that you thought was really silly for missing a really obvious problem? Let's have a contest to help you tell everyone about it!

This contest has one phase: Nomination and Voting. It is currently in the **Nomination and Voting** phase.

1. **Nomination and Voting** - ending March 22, 2019

   Post an answer to this Meta post containing a link to the Mi Yodeya post you want to nominate. Posts that are **already posted** are eligible (no, not including [Purim Torah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated) answers). Posts nominated [last year](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4509/9682) are ineligible; we’ve critiqued those enough already.

   Please link to one post in each entry. Nominate as many posts as you like in separate answers to this post.

   *When you see a big problem, don't wait; post a link to it here before you forget!*

   Please *do* vote on any answers to this post during the Nomination and Voting phase.

[image: 300-point Bounty button][2]]

The author of the highest voted answer to this meta post will receive a bounty of approximately 300 points after completion of the event on March 22, 2019, if I get around to it. In case of a tie, I will just keep the points to myself.

---

<sup>Concept and words stolen from [Meta.MY](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-contest).</sup>

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

---

## Moreover, answers must critique in the spirit of [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah). Critiques which are not offered in jest (or which are but end up as mean) will be deleted as nonanswers!

Comment: Previously: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4509/ptij-worst-post-contest-5778

Comment: Technically comments are posts, too. Can I nominate comments?

Comment: @DonielF *technically* comments are not posts.  Questions and answers (and tag wikis and a [bunch of other things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/162102)) are posts; comments are comments.

Answer (score 11):

I want to nominate my answer to to worst post contest because it doesn't actually fulfill the criteria because its on meta not MY itself and is ptij which was explicitly excluded and is written really poorly like without adequate punctuation also it doesnt even include a link to the answer that was requested

Comment: Here's a link you can add: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4953/1713

Comment: @Daniel my answer is perfectly good it doesnt need your link

Comment: Don’t have time to nominate this answer right now

Comment: <seriously>This answer was posted for fun but can't actually win the prize, since it doesn't meet the criteria of nominating a non-PTIJ-answer post on MY.</seriously>

Answer (score 5):

I want to nominate [this post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4952/). It’s a blatant rip-off of a [previous competition](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4509/), and unlike then, there’s no guarantee of an actual reward (“if I get around to it,” puh-leeze). It’s clearly a bad idea, because the only submission thus far [isn’t even a real submission](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4953/).

Further, the OP only excluded Purim Torah *answers*, leaving Purim Torah questions available, and the wording of “already posted” is sufficiently ambiguous as to allow critiques at this post itself. What a loser!

Comment: This is proper meta!

Comment: Am I nogei'a badavar by posting this? I can't win because I'm nogei'a, and msh can't win, because it doesn't satisfy the rules of the competition. I guess nobody gets the points; am I obligated to burn them?

Comment: @DonielF Just throw them into [Yam HaMelach](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Avodah_Zarah.3.9?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=he)

Comment: @JoelK Maybe I should set it aside until Eliyahu comes. How do I do that with reputation points?